# ClassCastException in Inheritance - Why?

Tags: java, inheritance, exception

Following code is throwing `ClassCastException` :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Child
>   cannot be cast to class java.util.List (Child is in unnamed module of
>   loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader
>   'bootstrap')  at Test.main(Test.java:20)

I am really not sure why it is behaving like this. I think I have written the correct code.

```
public class Test {
    public void a(ParentI... ss) {
    }

    public void a(List<ParentI> ss) {
    }


    public <R extends ParentI> R makeParent() {
        ParentI ai = new Child();
        return (R) ai;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test al = new Test();
        al.a(al.makeParent());
    }
}


interface ParentI {
    public void a();
}

class Parent implements ParentI {
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void a(int t) {
        System.out.println("child");
    }
}
```

Please help me understand this and how to fix this as well.

Comment: A full stacktrace and the line where the Exception occurs would be really helpful.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Does any one else got this exception or its me only, I am unsing intellij

Comment: There's still no stacktrace and no hint to the line causing the exception.

Comment: Exception is caused at `al.a(al.makeParent());`

Comment: @Nicktar - This is what I got on intellij console only.

Comment: guys why close vote :(

Answer (score 3):

The compiler infers the type returned by `al.makeParent()` according to the `a()` method being chosen by the method overloading resolution.

Since the method overloading resolution first considers candidates that don't have vararg arguments, only the `public void a(List<ParentI> ss)` overload is considered, and therefore that's the chosen overload.

The reason `public void a(List<ParentI> ss)` can accept as its argument the return value of a method that returns `R extends ParentI` is that there may exist a class that extends `ParentI` and implements `List<ParentI>`.

Once the `public void a(List<ParentI> ss)` overload is chosen, the casting in `return (R) ai;` causes an attempt to cast a `Child` instance to a `List`, which fails in runtime.

If, for example, you changed the definition of `Child` class to:

```
class Child extends Parent implements List<ParentI>
```

your code would run without exception.

Answer (score 1):

while I do not have the answer as to why the exception is thrown. I have managed to edit the code so that the program runs successfully. the `makeParent()` method needs to be modified so it is not generic:

```
public ParentI makeParent() {
    ParentI ai = new Child();
    return ai;
}
```

which basically is the same as before.

then, the correct overloaded `a()` is called